# load multi-dimensional array into a data file in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

In C++, how to implement the following functionality? Thanks.
Assume  in a program, I can get a matrix A = [1,2;2,1]. How to save it in an independent data file, e.g., data1.

Secondly, how to load this file data1 into my another program 2 as a matrix A.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/

Comment: Here's a [tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struct for C++ File I/O binary file sample

```
       struct WebSites
       {
             char SiteName[100];
             int Rank;
       };
```

to write

```
     void write_to_binary_file(WebSites p_Data)
     {
          fstream binary_file("test.dat",ios::out|ios::binary|ios::app);
          binary_file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&p_Data),sizeof(WebSites));
     }
```

Sample for C++ File I/O binary file read

```
 void read_from_binary_file()
 {
     WebSites p_Data;
     fstream binary_file("test.dat",ios::binary|ios::in);
     binary_file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&p_Data),sizeof(WebSites));
     binary_file.close();

     cout<<p_Data.SiteName<<endl;
     cout<<"Rank :"<< p_Data.Rank<<endl;
 }
```